# Apex stacked chart bar is not showing in the proper x-axis

Tags: angular, typescript, charts, apexcharts, ng-apexcharts

I am using the Apex stacked bar chart in my Angular 16 application. Here I have 4 categories in the x-axis, and the bar is not coming in the proper x-axis label.

My API response data:

```
let data = [
      {
        tenantName: 'OBC+',
        labelName: 'Application',
        total: 85,
        postiveTotal: '21',
        negativeTotal: '-64',
      },
      {
        tenantName: 'Discovery-world',
        labelName: 'Application',
        total: 194,
        postiveTotal: '119',
        negativeTotal: '-75',
      },
      {
        tenantName: 'OBC+',
        labelName: 'Channels',
        total: 40,
        postiveTotal: '0',
        negativeTotal: '-40',
      },
      {
        tenantName: 'OBC+',
        labelName: 'Wifi',
        total: 1,
        postiveTotal: '1',
        negativeTotal: '1',
      },
      {
        tenantName: 'Discovery-world',
        labelName: 'Channels',
        total: 59,
        postiveTotal: '0',
        negativeTotal: '-59',
      },
      {
        tenantName: 'Vidocon',
        labelName: 'Test',
        total: 30,
        postiveTotal: '10',
        negativeTotal: '-20',
      },
    ];
```

[image]

Please check the above image. The API response here `tenantName: 'Vidocon'`, the series data is not coming in the proper x-axis label.

It is supposed to show in the 'Test' x-axis label but it is shown in the 'Application' x-axis label.

[Example Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jq8xmc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each bar, the `data` array should contain the values with the size based on your x-axis category.

1. Split the data with the `positiveTotal` and `negativeTotal` fields to two different objects.
2. Get the `categoryGroups` which is an array of `name` values from the `newData`. Example: "OBC+ Positive", "OBC+ Negative", "Discovery-world Positive" and etc.
3. Form the `subLabels` array by iterating the `categoryGroups` array and form the object with the `data` based on the above concept.

```
let newData = data
  .map((x) => [
    {
      labelName: x.labelName,
      group: x.tenantName,
      name: x.tenantName + ' Positive',
      value: x.postiveTotal,
    },
    {
      labelName: x.labelName,
      group: x.tenantName,
      name: x.tenantName + ' Negative',
      value: x.negativeTotal,
    },
  ])
  .reduce((acc, cur) => {
    acc.push(cur[0]);
    acc.push(cur[1]);

    return acc;
  }, []);


let labels = [...new Set(data.map((x: any) => x.labelName))];
let categoryGroups = [...new Set(newData.map((x) => x.name))];

let subLabels = categoryGroups.map((category) => {
  return {
    group: newData.find(x => x.name == category).group,
    name: category,
    data: labels.map(
      (label) =>
        newData.find((z) => z.name == category && z.labelName == label)
          ?.value ?? 0
    ),
  };
});
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zgyxcm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer
can I get the result like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ysvarn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: Hi @RameshS, revised answer and also the demo link. But based on your expected data, I think the values that fall under the Channels have issue, which is conflicted with the original data.

Comment: Thanks for the help bro form your code I learned  may things